Geometry Nodes - Instance on Points with vertical Array
I currently have spheres that have been instanced along a curve, and would like to make a vertical array of said geometry?


Create another "instance on points" node.
In the "points" socket, connect the mesh line
In the "instance" socket, connect the output of the "instance on points" you already created.

Amazing Thank you! Would you be able to confirm whether this is possible with extra object? i.e introduce a random series of cubes as well as spheres along this curve?

@TheVisionTunnel, it is. If you create these objects individually, you put them inside a collection, and for the "instance" of the "instance on points" you connect a "collection info" node. (The collection info node must have "separate children" enabled).    ---- If you create the objects inside the geometry nodes as you did with the sphere string, you must convert them to instance, and join geometry, and they will behave as a collection.

This worked! Thank you very much
